# Accessibility: How to configure "column header" announcement?

Tags: html, web, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on optimizing a website for visually impaired. I have a table on the page in the following format -

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently the screen reader is announcing "row 1 col 1 number" but the expectation is that it should announce "row 1 col 1 number **column header**" when its a  element. How can I configure it? Setting role="columnheader" is not working.

Answer (score 2):

It is `scope` you are looking for to associate columns and rows.

`scope="col"` will associate a table header as a column header.

You can also associate a row header if you wish with `scope="row"`

```html
<table>
  <caption>My table caption - don't forget this so people know what a table is for / about</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
      <td>Simmons</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63.html for more info on this technique.

p.s. don't forget to add a `<caption>` to your table!